# JavaFX: Binding to insets

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, data-binding, javafx-bindings

I am pretty new to JavaFX and is fascinated by the binding capability. However, I could not figure out how to bind to the margin/padding of a node.

Currently, I am trying to make a textbox (or TextField) that has an image on the left. I made a StackPane to wrap around the TextField, as well as an ImageView to that StackPane. Then I tried binding the ImageView's height property to TextField's height property, but the image does not visually look like it's inside the TextField, because it is overlapping with the TextField's borders.

I ended up modifying the binding to account for the TextField's padding.

```
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(textField.heightProperty().subtract(textField.getPadding().getTop() + textField.getPadding().getBottom()));
```

It is working, but the part that the paddings are not bound is making me feel uneasy, because this value is counted as a constant which is equivalent to whatever padding it has when I set the binding. Things are going to go haywire if the padding is changed again after the binding.

This is an [example](http://webuikits.com/sign-in-widget/) of the textfield I want to achieve.

Is there a better way to do it? Either a better binding method, or a totally different approach to make an UI similar to the example. The current approach is not elegant because I am also setting a fixed amount of left padding so that the TextField content does not overlap with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own binding using [`Bindings.createDoubleBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createDoubleBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-):

```
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 
    textField.getHeight() - (textField.getPadding().getTop() + textField.getPadding().getBottom())
, textField.paddingProperty(), textField.heightProperty()));
```

If you check the method signature:

```
public static DoubleBinding createDoubleBinding(Callable<Double> func, Observable... dependencies)
```

and the javadoc of [`DoubleBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleBinding.html):

> If One of the registered dependencies becomes invalid, this
>   DoubleBinding is marked as invalid.

with this binding if the height or the padding of the `TextField` has been changed, the binding will be re-evaluated.